# ChronicleMap is accessing OS folders & files

Tags: java, jna, chronicle-map

While creating a ChronicleMap using the build, it is trying to access(read/write) the following OS(Mac) folders.

1. Read on "/usr/lib" & "/lib"
2. Read & Write on "/Users/userx/Library/Caches/JNA/temp"

I am trying to understand the reason on why these folder access are happening so that I can justify to our security team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Chronicle Map but rather with JNA library we use for native access.
`/usr/lib` contains native libraries (like libc), and `$HOME/Library/Caches/JNA/temp` is used by JNA to store its caches (see [here](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/Native.java#L1277) for the code, and some context can be found [here](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/issues/985))